# Avoiding Global Variables For Configuration File Reading in C

Tags: c, variables, global, configuration-files

My project is developed in C under linux platform. I am also using libxml2 . The executable consists of multiple modules distributed in multiple c files.

I have a configuration file ( Xml ) with 20 configurable parameters.

Let us say I am reading the configuration file parameters in Module M1. But I need them in other big modules M2 and M3.

Is there any efficient way to make the configurable parameters available to all the modules without using global variables to read parameters in module M1.

Specifically is there any other method / design to avoid using globally declared variables to read configuration parameters.

Comment: In C to share a variable among several modules you should use `extern` keyword, with global variables.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  I think you need to explain a little more what your problem is. I can see two separate aspects of the situation, either or both of which might be at issue. (1) Is the problem how to create a structure which can be used in all the modules to provide the data, or (2) how to associate strings from the XML configuration file with specific variables in the program? Clearly, for (1), you can arrange to bundle the variables into a `struct`, and you can either use a global copy of the `struct` or pass pointers around.  (2) takes more work.

Comment: Jonathan Thanks for the reply. The problem is not creation of structure. I have multiple nodules with many global variables. Reading the configuration file entries into global variable is an easy option. But let us say I add more entries or delete entries from the file. In that case again I need to add/remove global variables.  I wanted to know whether any better design strategy is available as alternative to global variables/structure.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23525820/694576

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if the values are read once and never changed after that, then storing them as global variables is not a big crime.

The best (general purpose) way to handle this, is to read the XML, convert the values to their native types (numbers as xml strings into integers), and stored collectively in a struct. There will be only one instanciation of the struct but don't stress over making it a "singleton".  That one struct can be globally accessible, or a pointer to it can be passed to the different modules.

Comment: Thanks James. Yeah my program will read the file once only. Thereafter only the contents will be accessed. SO whatever you told is absolutely correct. But let us say I add more entries or delete entries from the file. In that case again I need to add/remove global variables. I wanted to know whether any better design strategy is available as alternative to global variables/structure

Comment: Actually, I was going to note that this is perfect for that, as the struct can grow, and since you are only passing a pointer around, the function signatures stay the same.

Comment: Thanks once again James.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, I would indeed use global variables, your variables do indeed seem to be used globally by all modules. However to mitigate the global name-space pollution you will want to place these variables into a struct.

Create a struct called ConfigGlobals or some other descriptive name and simply add members to it for each configuration option. This adds clarity as you know which variables are config at a glance and means you are only throwing one name into the global scope.

EDIT: Note I see this answer is similar to James Curran's answer, I am sorry, the duplication is completely coincidental and I did not intentionally copy you, I had began writing this before you posted.

Comment: Thanks Vality for your reply. I did not mind at all. I appreciate your efforts in answering my Qt.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes using `global` variables is not such a big mess, but in order to improve encapsulation and avoid some other issues, you might want to consider using a `struct` instead.

This way, you declare your `configStruct` once, and pass it around from function to function that will use it.

This will be A LOT more cumbersome, having to pass the struct back and forth, specially for deep nested functions that might need it, but you have the advantage of being able to control your data and avoid global issues.

Another advantage is being able to have multiple configurations that can be used and chosen at runtime.

This can go as something like:

```
typedef struct configs
{
    int config1;
    // other configuration variables....
} configs;

int main(void)
{
    configs myConfigs;
    loadConfigs(&myConfigs);
    operateRobot(&myConfigs);
    // rest of the program

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Imho you need to pass only the variables the function is concerned with and not the whole config struct. Otherwise every function will have a config parameter, which is nonsense. You can use nested structs for big applications. The whole thing is similar to dependency injection + config in OOP.

Comment: I think you are extrapolating the concept. This is only about how to deal with configurations, where configurations are needed, if a function doesn't need a configuration don't pass it. This is a very common pattern in embedded systems, where the inner state of the electronics need to be shared across several functions that will deal with the inner hardware layer.

Comment: I meant that if a function needs only a small part of the configuration, then why not pass that part instead of the whole struct. It makes the whole thing easier to read and test, and that's what we usually do for example by webapplications too. I think it is a general concept, I am not sure though whether it has a name.

Comment: In that case I agree, but in some cases there will be several functions that will need the same immutable configurations, for example, think about a communications module, that needs to know the clock, selected ports, baud rate, etc, it's a lot easier, more readable and faster to create the struct once and pass it to `read()` and `write()` than to place all those non-changing data on each of this functions.

Comment: I think it depends on. :-) There is a balance in it, just like in everything if we are talking about programming. If there would be a dozen params, then better to pass the whole struct instead. If there would be only 1 param, then better to pass that instead of the struct. It's just my opinion though.

Comment: Yes, precisely!

Answer (score 1):

A better approach for your problem would be:
1- Have all your configuration variables in a single structure
2- Make a STATIC variable of that structure (So the scope is only in that file)
3- Use getter and setter to read and write your parameters

By doing this way if tommorrow you are making your application multi-threaded then you can protect your parameters by a mutex at only in the Setter and getter.
By this way it would be a more clean method of accessing...

Comment: Thanks Ginu for the answer. But through this method will the parameters read be available to all the other modules. Can you explain in slightly more details.

Comment: You can add the GETTER/SETTER in the header file and this header can be included in others to get the access

Comment: Thanks Ginu once again.

Answer (score 0):

How does one of your modules use the capabilities of another such module? Possibly you have a small number of functions that are exported using extern statements?

Have a module dedicated to managing the configuration and have it export some suitable accessor functions.

Comment: Most of my shared resources are either global variables or structures. Hence they are easily available to all the modules. But I want to know any other design paradigm is available to avoid global variables.